# Dragging parent div, while mousedown on draggable child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

When a div is clicked, fires function, in which, on mousedown, new div is created, and in that new div the clicked one and some others are appended (all of those appended divs are have draggable plugin on them). My question is: how do I drag the new div? As you will notice, I tried using handle, but failed.

```
var game = this;
var cardOldLocationId;

var tempWraperSelector;

$('#playArea').children().on('mousedown', function(event) {

  tempWraperSelector = $('<div id="multipleCardSelector"> </dv>');

  $(tempWraperSelector).appendTo('#' + $(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id'));

  cardOldLocationId = $(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id');

  var selectedCardIndex;
  var cardsToAppend = [];
  var pressedRowLenght = game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]].length;

  for (var i = 0; i < game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]].length; i++) {
    if (game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]][i].Taskai + "_" + game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]][i].Simbolis === $(event.target).attr('id')) {
      selectedCardIndex = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var j = selectedCardIndex; j < pressedRowLenght; j++) {
    var cardSelector = '#' + game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]][j].Taskai + "_" + game.options.rows[$(event.target).parent().parent().attr('id').split('_')[0]][j].Simbolis;
    cardsToAppend.push(cardSelector);
  }

  for (var k = 0; k < cardsToAppend.length; k++) {
    $(cardsToAppend[k]).parent().appendTo(tempWraperSelector);
  }

  $(tempWraperSelector).draggable({
    handle: '#' + $(event.target).attr('id')
  });

});

$('#playArea').children().on('mouseup', function(event) {
  $(tempWraperSelector).children().appendTo('#' + cardOldLocationId);
  $(tempWraperSelector).remove();
});
```

Comment: I would consider using `start` to add the new items from within Draggable. This way, when you add the items, they are appended to it already and will move or be dragged as the parent is dragged.

Comment: @Twisty Thanks, that was a great idea!